# copy folder skips some subfolders - Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: file-copy

On Ubuntu 21.10 - I have been using "file manager" to copy a folder with several subfolders.
Yesterday I found out that only two of sub-folders are actually copied...
There is no indication / feedback what folders are being successfully  copied...

It is very important to me - the copy is a backup of my C++ code!

Please advise what am I doing wrong and how to rectify this - using local
Linux tools - I am not in favor to "do github".

Answer (score 0):

Some GUI file managers have bugs like that.

If you're comfortable with using terminal, you could use `rsync` and automate that backup. If you want a GUI equivalent, there is `Grsync`.

This command installs both:

```
sudo apt install rsync grsync
```

Read `man rsync` for all the options you can set up.

**This** is the command I personally use for my backups:

```
rsync -avhWn --info=progress2 --delete-before /source /destination
```

where the options mean:

- `-a` archive
- `-v` verbose
- `-h` preserve hard links
- `-W` copy files whole
- `-n` dry run
- `--info=progress2` progress status
- `--delete-before` **Deletes all files in the destination** that are not present in the source, basically syncing 1 way.

In order to automate it, you write the `rsync` script/command you want to use, and put it in `crontab -e`.

You can use [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/) to figure out when you want your script to run.

I hope this helped.